# Apollo: Difference Between Subscription vs Query Resolvers?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

This resolver is working correctly:

```
const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        instant_message(_, args) {
            var ret = connectors.IM.findAll({ where: args }).then((res) => res.map((item) => item.dataValues));
            return ret;
        }
    },
    Subscription: {
    //[.....]
        },
    }

};
```

Does it make sense to use the exact same code for the subscription resolver as for the query resolver? I.e.:

```
const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        instant_message(_, args) {
            var ret = connectors.IM.findAll({ where: args }).then((res) => res.map((item) => item.dataValues));
            return ret;
        }
    },
    Subscription: {
        instant_message(_, args) {
            var ret = connectors.IM.findAll({ where: args }).then((res) => res.map((item) => item.dataValues));
            return ret;
        }
    }

};
```

If not what differences are required? Thanks in advance to all for any info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you would like to receive the same data in a subscription result that you receive in the query result, it would make sense to have the same logic. In that case, it might make sense to share the actual implementation:

```
// Used in both query and subscription field
function instant_message(root, args) {
  return connectors.IM.findAll({ where: args }).then((res) => res.map((item) => item.dataValues));
}

const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        instant_message,
    },
    Subscription: {
        instant_message,
    },
};
```

The biggest difference between queries and subscriptions is that subscriptions might receive additional information from the pub-sub message. For example, in the GitHunt example we have a `commentAdded` subscription resolver which uses the data from the pub-sub payload and doesn't hit the database at all: https://github.com/apollostack/GitHunt-API/blob/cc67a4506c31310b4ba8d811dda11d258c7d60d6/api/schema.js#L166-L171